# Is a string containing a single character same as a char?

Tags: java, string, char, character

Is a string containing a single character same as a char ? It seems java treats a single character string as a string itself, but I am not sure.

Comment: What does "the same" mean? They certainly aren't the same type anyway...

Comment: `String` and `char` are two different types, even if they contain same data.

Answer (score 2):

No. Infact String can contain *nothing* at all.
Example : `String s=""` is still a String.

Answer (score 1):

A char is a primitive type, while a String is a an object. Primitive types don't have methods associated, while a String object does. If your string object is a single letter, the array storing it would have a single char, but all these string methods would still work on it. [String Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Without a [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) wrapper, the single char would not have any methods associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

They are different.

You can find this out very easily - simply try to assign one to the other:

```
String s = 'c';
char s = "s";
```

Both will generate 'incompatible types' compile errors.

Furthermore, they are *fundamentally* different things. A char is a primitive type, a string is a reference type. A `char` value is the single character itself represented as a 2-byte number, a `String` value is a reference to (essentially) an array of characters elsewhere in memory.

Answer (score 0):

No, "c" is a string while 'c' is a char, the quotations determine the type

Answer (score 0):

You see when you declare a `String` it starts with capital `S` which means it is a class from `java.lang package` While a `char` is a data type which can hold any single character and not a class.

Answer (score 0):

A String containing a single character is not the same as a char.  They both can be declared using quotes 
(single quotes for chars and double quotes for Strings), but they are very different.

A char is a primitive data type just like int, boolean, long, etc; while a String is an Object.[1][2]

At a high level, a way to think about it is that a String is an Object that allows you to operate on a sequence of chars.

When thinking about variables, it may be helpful to think about it in two parts, the type and value.

The type of a variable is specified when it is declared and given a name. In this case, our types would be char and String.

The value is what we assign to the variable with the equals sign.

While two variables, in spirit, may represent the same value, if their types are different they cannot be considered the same.

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

[2] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html